# how to get rows in google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I Want To Get All The Rows And Columns In Google Spreadsheet so i can iterate over them horizontally but everytime i am trying to fetch the rows it is giving me an error please help

here is my code:

```
const GoogleSpreadSheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const app = require('express')()

async function accessSpreadSheet() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadSheet('1UkcGReVvw5Ea1IbamdFc45PWZBKXEUJI6paxO_AWwMk');
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)()
    console.log(`Title: ${info.title}`)
    const rows = await promisify(info.worksheets.getRows({
        offset: 1
    }))
    console.log(rows)
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const info = await accessSpreadSheet()
    res.send(info)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('served')
})
```

Comment: Which error are you receiving? Also, are you using a service account?

Comment: yeah i am using a server account

Comment: and the error is that getRows Is Not A Function

Comment: but if you know a more advanced way to get rows or even cells or columns just post it and i will be happy with it 

Comment: Does `worksheets` have multiple elements? Please bear in mind that `getRows` is a method that can be called from a sheet.

Comment: [here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit)

Comment: Just like mentioned above, what does the `info.worksheets` variable contain?

Comment: tell me how to add image and i will show you

Comment: Why do you use `promisify`? You can directly use `await`

Comment: Or is it an old version?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet#working-with-rows), the `getRows` method is called from a singular sheet.

So in order to solve this, you will have to loop through all the sheets from the spreadsheet and later call the `getRows` method or just use a single sheet.

#### Example

```
const sheet = doc.worksheets[0]; // the first sheet
const rows = await sheet.getRows();
console.log(rows[0].PROPERTY1);
```

You can also start by taking a look at the examples from the [Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values).

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using javascript API. I usually use Python, yet the Google Sheet API is the same.

I guess you trying to loop through all the rows in the sheet which contains data. In such case why don't you use getDataRange(), then loop through the resultant range?

The official reference has an example on how this works:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()

Comment: but i am using the `google-sheets` npm package